# snowflake timezone convert function is not converting

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, timezone-offset

I am reading times from a snowflake DB in UTC/GMT, for example as

```
2021-12-14T18:11:32.753+00:00
2021-12-18T18:11:10.529+00:00
2021-12-20T00:02:02.781+00:00
```

I want to convert these to AEST(GMT+11), so I use the following statement:
`convert_timezone('Australia/Melbourne', artifact_generated_at) as time2`

But this seems to only convert the time zone component and doesn't actually convert the time.

```
2021-12-14T18:11:32.753+11:00
2021-12-18T18:11:10.529+11:00
2021-12-20T00:02:02.781+11:00
```

any thoughts? or should I be using a different function?

Comment: how are you "ingesting those values into snowflake"?

Answer (score 1):

I used
`CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', 'Australia/Melbourne', artifact_generated_at)` 
which worked fine.

Comment: it would seem you input was "already in the destination timeszone" thus the lack of change, but the soruce_tz, dest_tz form of the covertion, is saying ignore what you think.